# Inviting an unemployed friend to visit the USA on a tourist visa

Tags: visas, usa, planning, b1-b2-visas

I am a PhD student currently in the US on an F1-Visa. I want to invite a friend, who is currently not employed. He also does not have sufficient funds, so I am willing to cover all the expenses involved. He stays with his parents.

He is planning an art exhibition in a few months and would like to tour US to draw inspiration from.

I have the invitation letter, affidavit of support(I-134), a formal letter addressed to the consulate and my bank/university salary statements ready. However given his unemployed status, I am a bit skeptical about procuring a visa.

1. What other documents would possibly increase the chances of getting a B2-Visa?
2. Is it okay to establish home ties by stating that my friend is bound to return given he has a scheduled art exhibition back home?

Comment: A lot depends on the nationalities involved (his and yours).  But as a whole, it is your friend who bears the responsibility of convincing the consular official of his desire to return home and his ability to support himself.  Your letters will be bonus, but unto themselves will likely not be enough.

Comment: That would help but a spouse and a kid would be better.

Comment: As the sponsor, it's not your place to attempt to help your friend establish ties to his home country in any information _you_ provide to the consulate. This will only look bad and make it more difficult for him. But being unemployed is not a bar to obtaining a visa.

Answer (score 3):

There is really no documentation that you can provide more then you already have to show ties outside the US for your unemployed friend.

There has to be something back home or anywhere outside the US to show that he/she would leave the country at the end of his visa.  A job goes a long way, so does his/her own business, kids, wife, parents to a lesser degree, real property to an even lesser degree.

Also what seems to be taken into consideration is visas to other G-7 countries that have been used, namely the person entered the country and then left.

Save that everything else is just paper.